# Re-add partitions to GRUB after installing Arch

Tags: archlinux, grub

While installing Arch Linux by following the beginner's guide at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide , I installed GRUB as my bootloader. However, on rebooting, I find my previous Ubuntu option has disappeared and I am left only with Arch.

I would like to know how I can re-add my other disk partitions to GRUB, as I can find no comprehensible tutorials anywhere else.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Boot to `archlinux` and run as root:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Make sure `os-prober` is installed if not then install it using:

```
pacman -S os-prober
```

Its there in [beginner's guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Install_and_configure_a_bootloader). Read Tip in green color.